# PHP MySQL, getting data from database only when second table says its visable

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to get all data from table backorder to only be shown when the visability

Is set to 1 in table ordervisible. Not sure how to get this to work.

```
$query = "
SELECT backorder.* 
  FROM ordervisible
     , backorder
 WHERE ordervisible.visability = 1

 ";
```

I'm very stuck advice would be appreciated.

Comment: What is ordervisible?

Comment: backorder and ordervisible are both tables in the same database

Comment: and do the tables relate in some way?

Comment: the both have id values

Comment: So ordervisible.id = backorder.id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are forgetting to join the 2 tables, it should be

```
SELECT backorder.* 
  FROM backorder JOIN ordervisible ON [INSERT CONDITION HERE]
 WHERE ordervisible.visability = 1
```

Comment: Thank you so much working as should no, should have just asked for help in the first place only 4 hours scratching my head.

Comment: Accept the answer so other people know that it helped you.